# upgrade chef-client version to 13 through a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

i would like to upgrade chef-client version to 13 through a recipe and would like to add a condition saying that if it already exists action : nothing . and i would to do in a particular directory . Could you let me know how can I achieve this .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef_client_updater is the cookbook you would want to use if you want to do in-band upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I want to upgrade to chef-client v 13 package .

Comment: Just in general?

Comment: I want to install and upgrade through recipe                                                               https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef/13.2.20/el/7/chef-13.2.20-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Then use the suggested cookbook.

Comment: [2017-08-30T15:01:42-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers   
  Running handlers complete 
[2017-08-30T15:01:42-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete   
  Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated in 40 seconds 
[2017-08-30T15:01:42-05:00] ERROR: cannot load such file -- enc/trans/single_byte

Comment: @StephenKing Do you have an answer . The first converge always fails when upgrade/Downgrade chef client using chef_client_updater.

Comment: If that's the error message, I have no clue. Search for bug reports, maybe try `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and friends.